# Take Profit 1 and Stop loss + Moving Stop loss

Tags: pine-script

I succeeded to make a buy and sell entries, but I couldn't code the take profit and Stop loss.
The conditions are as follows:

1. TP1 close 50% of the entry trade on the high of the "ATR Stop Loss Finder" Indicator, from the high value of the of the ATR  **of the previous candle of the entry bar**
2. Stop loss on the low value of the of the ATR  **of the pervious candle of the entry bar**

If TP1 reached:

1. Move SL to the entry Level

If double of TP1 reached so move the SL again from the entry level to the half length between TP1 and the entry and so on as follows.

If triple of TP1 reached so move the SL again from the pervious level to the half length between the double TP1 and the entry and so on as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd9H9.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVsKu.jpg)

```
Buy = direction<0 and buySignal
plotshape(Buy, style = shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, color = color.green)

Sell = direction>0 and sellSignal
plotshape(Sell, style = shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, color = color.red)

longCondition = Buy
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)


shortCondition = Sell
if (shortCondition)
strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Comment: I don't understand 'TP1 close 50% of the entry trade on the high of the "ATR Stop Loss Finder" Indicator, from the high value of the of the ATR of the previous candle of the entry bar'. Your entry trade seems to be at the market price, but how is calculated the high of the ATR SL Finder ? What do you mean by 'from the high value....' ?

Comment: I added 2 Pictures, Please see them

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your entry, you can also declare your stop loss this way :

```
QTY = 12
var buyprice = 0.0
if (longCondition)
    buyprice := close
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, qty = QTY, limit=buyprice)
    
    StopLoss = x2 // x2 is the value of the ATR SL Finder indicator for the green line

    strategy.exit(id='Exit', from_entry="My Long Entry Id", stop=StopLoss, qty = QTY*(50/100) )
///////////////////////    
var wintrades = 0
var losstrades = 0

/////////////////////////////////
// Result of the trade
if strategy.opentrades == 0 // No open order
    Q_Jetons := 0.0
    // An order has just been closed
    if strategy.losstrades > tradesperdus or strategy.wintrades > tradesgagnes
        strategy.exit(id='Exit', from_entry="My Long Entry Id", stop=buyprice, qty = QTY*(50/100) )
```

Comment: First, thank you for your reply. The point that I want it close 50% of the trade when reach X in the long situation. also to move the SL to the entry. can you help me in that?

Comment: @Karim if you want to close 50% of the trade, you must first give a quantity for your entry. I edit my answer so you can see.

Comment: That's great, it works fine. could you please tell me how to move SL to the entry point when the price reach the TP1

Comment: @Karim if you want to move the SL to the entry point, you must record the value of your entry point (buyprice in the code). I edit my answer so you can see.

Comment: I failed, could you please make it for me based on the pictures attached

Comment: @Karim it is already on the answer

Comment: @Karim 'That's great, it works fine' please accept this answer and post a new one for more clarity.